# BlackBerry WebWorks app crush: multi-page

Tags: navigation, blackberry-webworks

I'm developing an WebWorks app with multi-page. My app have home page and link to table view. And table view link to page detail. When i navigate between each page(go in and go back) my app crush.

I can't figure out what the exact cause of the crush since the code is pretty simple. link to another page only, nothing else.

any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may want to test the html, css (and js) files on a local server first to ensure that your code is actually correct. Try removing the javascript files to see if they are the source of the error. If they are, make sure you have the right versions of the code/plugins that you are trying to use.

If that doesn't work, please post a sample of your code so someone can help.